# Obtain coordinates on doubleTap using Zepto-js and iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, mobile, zepto

Anybody familiar with zepto?

I'm open to other mobile frameworks suggestions,too if they have good implantation of  doubleTap and they handle the job.

I need to detect coordinates on the second tap of doubleTap event in mobile Safari.

So far I've been using **jQuery** for the event-obj and that syntax was fine

```
 x: e.pageX 
 y: e.pageY
```

But it doesn't work in iPad

Appreciate any kind help, BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned I found a solution so I'm posting it if other users face the same issue:

```
// double tap (tapped twice within 250ms)
      if (touch.isDoubleTap) {
        touch.el.trigger('doubleTap')
        touch = {}
```

This code above in zepto.js  detects that the touch event was doubleTap and triggers its handler. And here is a little modification:

```
 // double tap (tapped twice within 250ms)
      ...............
        touch.el.trigger('doubleTap', {touch: touch})
```

overriding it with passing the event as parameter solves the problem. Now the event object is accessible  with all its properties including coordinates.

And here is an example how you extract them from defined handler:

```
    Zepto('selector').doubleTap(function(e){
       var dblTap = e.data.touch;
       var coord = {
          x: dblTap.x1,
          y: dblTap.y1
       }
    });
```

This is valid for **v1.0.rc1** don't know what the case will be in future releases

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can be made to work on Zepto (I'm having the same issue on JQMobi) but if you use HammerJS http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/ instead you can get the actual position of the tap

See my SoftPaws game for an example of this: https://github.com/gavD/soft-paws

I hope this helps!

Comment: 10x I'll check it out appreciate your concern.
I've overrode Zepto because the problem is the events object isn't passed on 'doubleTap' as parameter since it's an event put together by two consecutive tap events in short period of time.
I'll post the solution here in future I've totally forgot about this issue :)